# Chart.js - remove labels

Tags: chart.js

I have a pie chart made in Chart.js. I want to remove the label on the chart NOT the legend. AKA the grey numbers. Any thoughts? Not much online about this.

[image]

Comment: can you share with as your javascript code that creates this pie chart, please ? you can find the labels within your javascript config for this pie chart

Comment: Not all my code. Can't share. But I would think this would have a fairly standard answer?

Comment: "Labels" in the chart.js documentation seem to refer to the legend, which is not what I want

Comment: What version of chart.js is this?  The docs (and most of my work) does have a label for each item, but they are only rendered as tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the HTML  link to chartjs-plugin-datalabels, and the labels should be gone